# Prolog - Help fixing a rule

Tags: database, prolog, rules, accumulator

I have a database full of facts such as:

```
overground(newcrossgate,brockley,2).
overground(brockley,honoroakpark,3).
overground(honoroakpark,foresthill,3).
overground(foresthill,sydenham,2).
overground(sydenham,pengewest,3).
overground(pengewest,anerley,2).
overground(anerley,norwoodjunction,3).
overground(norwoodjunction,westcroydon,8).
overground(sydenham,crystalpalace,5).
overground(highburyandislington,canonbury,2).
overground(canonbury,dalstonjunction,3).
overground(dalstonjunction,haggerston,1).
overground(haggerston,hoxton,2).
overground(hoxton,shoreditchhighstreet,3).
```

example: newcrossgate to brockley takes 2 minutes.

I then created a rule so that if I enter the query istime(newcrossgate,honoroakpark,Z). then prolog should give me the time it takes to travel between those two stations. (The rule I made is designed to calculate the distance between any two stations at all, not just adjacent ones).

```
istime(X,Y,Z):- istime(X,Y,0,Z); istime(Y,X,0,Z).
istime(X,Y,T,Z):- overground(X,Y,Z), T1 is T + Z.
istime(X,Y,Z):- overground(X,A,T), istime(A,Y,T1), Z is T + T1.
istime(X,Y,Z):- overground(X,B,T), istime(B,X,T1), Z is T + T1.
```

it seems to work perfectly for newcrossgate to the first couple stations, e.g newcrossgate to foresthill or sydenham. However, after testing newcrossgate to westcroydon which takes 26mins, I tried newcrossgate to crystalpalace and prolog said it should take 15 mins...despite the fact its the next station after westcroydon. Clearly somethings wrong here, however it works for most of the stations while coming up with a occasional error in time every now and again, can anyone tell me whats wrong? :S

Comment: Is the last clause correct? You seem to be going from X to B, then from B to X. When do you go to Y?

Answer (score 2):

This is essentially the same problem as your previous question, the only difference is that you need to accumulate the time as you go.

One thing I see is that your "public" predicate, `istime/3` tries to do too much. All it should do is seed the accumulator and invoke the worker predicate `istime/4`. Since you're looking for route/time in both directions, the public predicate should be just

```
istime( X , Y , Z ) :- istime( X , Y , 0 , Z ) .
istime( X , Y , Z ) :- istime( Y , X , 0 , Z ) .
```

The above is essentially the first clause of your `istime/3` predicate

```
istime(X,Y,Z):- istime(X,Y,0,Z); istime(Y,X,0,Z).
```

The remaining clauses of `istime/3`, the recursive ones:

```
istime(X,Y,Z):- overground(X,A,T), istime(A,Y,T1), Z is T + T1.
istime(X,Y,Z):- overground(X,B,T), istime(B,X,T1), Z is T + T1.
```

should properly be part of `istime/4` and have the accumulator present. That's where your problem is.

Give it another shot and edit your question to show the next iteration. If you still can't figure it out, I'll show you some different ways to do it.

**Some Hints**

1. Your "worker" predicate will likely look a lot like your earlier "find a route between two stations" exercise, but it will have an extra argument, the accumulator for elapsed time.
2. There are two special cases. If you use the approach you used in your "find a route between two stations" solution, the special cases are

   - A and B are directly adjacent.
   - A and B are connected via at least one intermediate stop.

There's another approach as well, that might be described as using lookahead, in which case the special cases are

- A and B are the same, in which case you're arrived.
- A and B are not and are connected by zero or more intermediate stops.

FWIW, You shouldn't necessarily expect the route with the shortest elapsed time or the minimal number of hops to be the first solution found. Backtracking will produce all the routes, but the order in which they are found has to do with the order in which the facts are stored in the database. A minimal cost search of the graph is another kettle of fish entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to cycle through answers with `;`? 26mins is **not** the shortest time between newcrossgate and westcroydon...

**Edit**: my bad! Apparently the shorter results were due to a bug in your code (see my comment about the 4th clause). However, your code is correct, 15mins is the shortest route between newcrossgate and crystalpalace. Only because there is a route that goes from newcrossgate to westcroydon, then crystalpalace, that doesn't mean it's the **shortest** route, or the route your program will yield first.

**Update**: if you're running into problems to find answers to some routes, I'd suggest changing the 3rd clause to:

```
istime(X,Y,_,Z):- overground(X,A,T), istime(A,Y,T1), Z is T + T1.
```

The reason is simple: your first clause swaps X with Y, which is good, since with that you're saying the routes are symmetrical. However, the 3rd clause does not benefit from that, because it's never called by the swapped one. Ignoring the 3rd argument (which you're not using anyway) and thus letting the 1st clause call the 3rd might fix your issue, since some valid routes that were not used previously will be now.

(also: I agree with Nicholas Carey's answer, it would be better to use the third argument as an accumulator; but as I said, ignoring it for now might just work)

Comment: I changed the last line of the code by changing the route from B to X into B to Y, I'm hoping thats what you meant. I'm testing now to see if its working perfectly.
istime(X,Y,Z):- overground(X,B,T), istime(B,Y,T1), Z is T + T1.

Comment: Damn doesn't seem to work... Every time I try one of the longer journeys such as richmond to barking I just get false...

Comment: @JimmyK not really, if you look closely, the changed clause is identical to the 3rd one (changing the name of the variable from A to B doesn't matter), so it will just repeat the calculation.

Comment: Hmm I'm not too sure what to do then, every time I read out the code in my head it seems to me like it should work fine... Oh and finding the shortest route doesnt really matter, as long as it works it works

Comment: @JimmyK I just updated my answer, see if it helps. Overall, your original code is fine, you just need to pay attention to some small details.

Comment: made the changes you suggested with the third and fourth line, however I still seem to be having the problem where if I pick two stations that are extremly far apart I get back a wrong time thats far too short like 15 mins

Comment: @JimmyK could you update your question showing what your current code look like, and what problems you're still facing? So I and other users can see if we can help you further. As I said, you were not far from solving the problem by yourself, I think you're just slipping in some minor detail...

Answer (score 1):

To make it work  you need to do the reverse of both journeys stated in your last clause. 
Keep the predicate as it is, istime(X,Y,Z) and just make another clause containing the reverse journeys. 
This way it works with all the stations. (Tried and Tested)

Comment: Hmm.. Doesnt seem to be working too well, I get two different times for the same exact journey done one way and then in reverse